# program giving error

Tags: c

The logic of the program is quite clear but when it asks the user to enter name. The second time it asks for the name i.e at i=1 it asks for the name and also asks for the year to be entered. In short its not allowing to the user to enter data after i=0 in  int year.

```
/* Write a program to take input name roll number and year of joining of 5 students and making a function which prints name of only those who have joined in the particular year mentioned by the user*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct student
{
   char name[50];
   int year;

}
a[5];

void func ( void );
void main ( void )
{
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
      printf ( "Enter name %d\n", i + 1 );
      gets ( a[i].name );
      puts ( "Enter year" );

      scanf ( "%d", &a[i].year );
   }
   func(); 
   getch();
}
void func ( void )
{
   int i;
   int yearr;
   printf ( "Enter a year:" );
   scanf ( "%d", &yearr );
   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
      if ( yearr == a[i].year )
      {
         printf ( "%s", a[i].name );
      }// if ends

   }//for ends
}// func ends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the input buffer before taking input using `fflush(stdin)` or `fflushall()`. Your modified code is given below.

```
/* Write a program to take input name roll number and year of joining of 5 students and making a function which prints name of only those who have joined in the particular year mentioned by the user*/
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    struct student
    {
       char name[50];
       int year;

    }
    a[5];

    void func ( void );
    void main ( void )
    {
       int i;
       for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
       {
          printf ( "Enter name %d\n", i + 1 );
          fflush(stdin);
          gets ( a[i].name );
          puts ( "Enter year" );

          scanf ( "%d", &a[i].year );
       }
       func(); 
       getch();
    }
    void func ( void )
    {
       int i;
       int yearr;
       printf ( "Enter a year:" );
       scanf ( "%d", &yearr );
       for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
       {
          if ( yearr == a[i].year )
          {
             printf ( "%s", a[i].name );
          }// if ends

       }//for ends
    }// func ends
```

Comment: Sorry, My program has some errors. Please don't use fflush(stdin). See http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php for more.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the code stink of `gets` (USE `fgets`.  PLEASE.  NOW, WHILE YOU'RE STILL LEARNING RIGHT FROM WRONG.), and the hideosity of your output (A `\n` here and there would do wonders), it looks like it could work.  Assuming what you want it to get 5 names and years from the user, then ask for a year to search for, and list all students' names whose years match.  (If that's not what you want, the logic isn't even nearly as clear as you think it is.)

Personally, i wouldn't be mixing `scanf` and `fgets` (Yes, i said `fgets`.  USE IT.), so i'm not sure about problems with doing so.  I'm not a fan of `scanf` anyway, so i may be biased.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to this question:
[Input in C. Scanf before gets. Problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366509/input-in-c-scanf-before-gets-problem)

Try:

```
scanf("%d\n", &yearr);
```