# Program doesn't execute gets() after scanf(), even using fflush(stdin)

Tags: c, scanf, gets, fflush

After wasting too much time searching why my program doesn't execute gets() after using scanf(), I found a solution which is to use fflush(stdin) after scanf() to enable gets() to get a string.

The problem is that fflush(stdin) doesn't do what is expected from it: The program continues skipping gets() and I can't write any phrase in the console to be read.

My code is the next one:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char nombre[10];
    char mensaje[80];

    printf("Type your name:\n");
    scanf("%s", nombre);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Now, type a message:\n");
    gets(mensaje);

    printf("3/%s:%s",nombre,mensaje);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin (unrelated to your issue though).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input in C. Scanf before gets. Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366509/input-in-c-scanf-before-gets-problem)

Comment: Change the last `printf` into `printf("3/%s:%s\n",nombre,mensaje);`

Comment: Michael it doesn't run good because when the program reaches that line, the message (mensaje) has to be written and I can't write anything because the gets() keeps skipping

Comment: Don't `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour. It has no expectation. On my compiler it just does nothing (which is arguably a better option than crashing).   The `fflush` function means to write any buffered output that hasn't been written yet, but `stdin` is not writable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If flushing std doesn't work, then try reading in the extra characters and discarding, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c).

This will work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char nombre[10];
    char mensaje[80];
    int c;

    printf("Type your name:\n");
    scanf("%9s", nombre);

    while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            /* discard */ ;

    printf("Now, type a message:\n");
    gets(mensaje);

    printf("%s:%s",nombre,mensaje);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you emsworth! It runs perfectly! ;)

Comment: True, I went ahead and removed it

Answer (score 4):

Two big, major issues:

1. **DO NOT USE `fflush` ON INPUT STREAMS**; the behavior of `fflush` on input streams is not defined.  Just because it *appears* to work in this situation does not mean it is correct.
2. **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER *NEVER*** use `gets` - it was deprecated in the C99 standard and has been removed completely from the C2011 standard.  It **will** (not might, *will*) introduce a major point of failure in your code.

It's never a good idea to follow a `scanf` call with a `gets` call, since `gets` won't skip over any leading newlines left in the input stream by `scanf`.  Use `scanf` to read *both* `nombre` and `mesaje`.

```
printf("Type your name:\n");
scanf("%9s", nombre);

printf("Now, type a message:\n");
scanf("%79s", mensaje);
```

It's a good idea to use an explicit length specifier in the `scanf` call for `%s` and `%[`, otherwise you introduce the same security hole that `gets` does.

**EDIT**

D'oh.  I'm an idiot.  If you're trying to read a string containing spaces, you can't use the `%s` conversion specifier.  Use the `%[` conversion specifier instead:

```
scanf( "%79[^\n]", mensage );
```

That will read up to the next 79 characters or the newline, whichever comes first, and leaves the newline in the input stream.

Comment: I don't know why, but happens the same if I use "%79s" or "%s": scanf only get the first word of the whole phrase, so that I've been using gets().

Comment: `scanf( "%79[^\n]", mensage );` after `scanf("%9s", nombre);` can easily read nothing as the first character may be `'\n'`.  `scanf( " %79[^\n]", mensage );` is a bit better, yet loses leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
scanf("%s\n", nombre);
```

scanf stops at whitespace when reading a part. gets reads until the first new line. So what happens is scanf leaves behind a newline in the buffer, which gets immediately sees and thinks it was given a blank line.

If you take your original code and enter "name message", two pieces all on one line, you can see this in action - gets will still immediately return, but it will see the second part.

The \n in the scanf thing tells it to go ahead and consume that too.

Comment: Thank you for answering but it's not the solution because after I enter the name, press enter and it keeps blank until I type something and press enter, then the console shows me "Now, type a message:"

Comment: Bad solution. `scanf("%s\n", nombre);` " tells it to go ahead and consume that too." and continue reading until non-white scape detected.  Then it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gets(stdin);` instead of

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: sorry, typo, my bad, use getc(stdin), instead of fflush(stdin), The fflush function does not flush data out of an input stream; it is instead used to push data buffered in an output stream.

Comment: Thank u Smitt! using getc(stdin) runs perfectly as well. Sorry, i've seen another answer first and accepted it, but I'll give you a positive vote at least. ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n'); // seems to work
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, user9816128. Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation? In the current form it is unlikely to attract upvotes.