# Delete last character of a string

Tags: c, c-strings, gets

why doesn't this code work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
// local declarations
int len;
char* pStr;

// statements
printf(" how many characters you want to enter?\n");
scanf("%d", &len);
pStr=(char*)calloc(len+1,sizeof(char));
printf("\n enter your string:  ");
gets(pStr);
*(pStr+len)='\0';
printf("\n your string: ");
puts(pStr);
printf(" oops! last character deleted.");

getch();
return 0;
}
```

although it runs correct, when i use scanf function to read the string, but
why it does not with gets?

Comment: *(pStr+len)     ->    *(pStr+len*sizeof(char))

Comment: Don't mix usage of scanf with gets . [check this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226529/program-doesnt-execute-gets-after-scanf-even-using-fflushstdin)

Comment: Asking the user how long the input will be is a questionable endeavor. *Trusting* the user's input to match is foolish. @K.Gkinis: Don't use `gets()`, period. It's removed from C for good reason.

Comment: @EOF I agree, no reason *not* to prefer scanf anyway.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf("%s", pStr)` skips to the first non-whitespace character while `gets` doesn't.

After the first `scanf` the trailing newline is still in the input buffer so that when you call `gets` the result is an empty line unless you entered extra characters after the number.

Note that `gets` is marked as *obsolete* due to serious security flaws.
It is recommended that any use of `gets(var)` is replaced with `fgets(var, length, stdin)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because arrays are zero based, and (assuming the input is valid and the correct length, assumption which your code ought not to make) `*(ptr + len)` already contains `\0` and you are just overwriting it.  You meant to overwrite `ptr[len-1]`

Comment: For great fun as the user, input `0` for the length.

Comment: The first element of the array is indexed by 0.  If the array A contains the string "foo", then `A[0] == 'f'`, `A[1] == 'o'`, `A[2] == 'o'`, and `A[3] == '\0'`.  Notice that `A[len("foo")] == '\0'`, so it doesn't change the string to overwrite it.

Comment: pStr is allocated memory for (len+1) bytes. '\0' will be at len +1; not len.

Comment: No, in the string "foo", which has length 3, the `\0` is in the "length + 1" position (eg, the "fourth"), which is at index 3, because arrays are zero based.  A[3] is the fourth element of the array.

Comment: See the statement in which I have allocated memory to pStr, it will be allocated a memory of (len+1) bytes. Let LEN=len+1. Now according to your logic ,string delimiter will be at LEN. In order to make last character null, I should code pStr[LEN-1]='\0', which is correct. Simplifying code we can write pStr[(len+1)-1] which is equivalent to pStr[len] or *(pStr +len), which is correct. This was exactly my logic.