# In C,why is my scanf input inside of a linked list node not being taken despite being mentioned in code?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 30

struct EMP {
    int empno;
    char empName[MAX];
    char designation[MAX];
    struct EMP *next;
};

/*********************************************************************/
/* Function to insert a node at the front of the linked list.        */
/* front: front pointer, id: employee ID, name: employee name        */
/* desg: Employee designation                                        */
/* Returns the new front pointer.                                    */
/*********************************************************************/

struct EMP *insert(struct EMP *front, int id, char name[], char desg[])
{
    struct EMP *newnode;

    newnode = (struct EMP *)malloc(sizeof(struct EMP));

    if (newnode == NULL) {
        printf("\nAllocation failed\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    newnode->empno = id;
    strcpy(newnode->empName, name);
    strcpy(newnode->designation, desg);
    newnode->next = front;
    front = newnode;
    return (front);
}                               /* End of insert() */

/* Function to display a node in a linked list */
void printNode(struct EMP *p)
{
    printf("\nEmployee Details...\n");
    printf("\nEmp No : %d", p->empno);
    printf("\nName : %s", p->empName);
    printf("\nDesignation : %s\n", p->designation);
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
}                               /* End of printNode() */

/* ******************************************************* */
/* Function to deleteNode a node based on employee number */
/* front: front pointer, id: Key value */
/* Returns: the modified list. */
/* ******************************************************* */

struct EMP *deleteNode(struct EMP *front, int id)
{
    struct EMP *ptr;
    struct EMP *bptr;           /* bptr is pointing to the node behind ptr */

    if (front->empno == id) {
        ptr = front;
        printf("\nNode deleted:");
        printNode(front);
        front = front->next;
        free(ptr);
        return (front);
    }
    for (ptr = front->next, bptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next, bptr = bptr->next) {
        if (ptr->empno == id) {
            printf("\nNode deleted:");
            printNode(ptr);
            bptr->next = ptr->next;
            free(ptr);
            return (front);
        }
    }
    printf("\nEmployee Number %d not found ", id);
    return (front);
}                               /* End of deleteNode() */

/*****************************************************************/
/* Function to search the nodes in a linear fashion based emp ID */
/* front: front pointer, key: key ID. */
/*****************************************************************/
void search(struct EMP *front, int key)
{
    struct EMP *ptr;

    for (ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        if (ptr->empno == key) {
            printf("\nKey found:");
            printNode(ptr);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("\nEmployee Number %d not found ", key);
}                               /* End of search() */

/* Function to display the linked list */
void display(struct EMP *front)
{
    struct EMP *ptr;

    for (ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printNode(ptr);
    }
}                               /* End of display() */

/* Function to display the menu of operations on a linked list */
void menu()
{
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press 1 to INSERT a node into the list \n");
    printf("Press 2 to DELETE a node from the list \n");
    printf("Press 3 to DISPLAY the list \n");
    printf("Press 4 to SEARCH the list \n");
    printf("Press 5 to EXIT \n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
}                               /* End of menu() */

/* Function to select the option */
char option()
{
    char choice;

    printf("\n\n>> Enter your choice: ");
    switch (choice = getche()) {
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
        return (choice);
    default:
        printf("\nInvalid choice.");
    }
    return choice;
}                               /* End of option() */

/* The main() program begins */
void main()
{
    struct EMP *linkList;
    char name[21], desig[51];
    char choice;
    int eno;

    linkList = NULL;

    printf("\nWelcome to demonstration of singly linked list\n");

    menu();                     /* Function call */

    do {
        choice = option();      /* to choose oeration to be performed */

        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            printf("\nEnter the Employee Number : ");
            scanf("%d", &eno);

            printf("Enter the Employee name : ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(name);

            printf("Enter the Employee Designation : ");
            gets(desig);

            linkList = insert(linkList, eno, name, desig);
            break;

        case '2':
            printf("\n\nEnter the employee number to be deleted: ");
            scanf("%d", &eno);

            linkList = deleteNode(linkList, eno);
            break;

        case '3':
            if (linkList == NULL) {
                printf("\nList empty.");
                break;
            }
            display(linkList);
            break;

        case '4':
            printf("\n\nEnter the employee number to be searched: ");
            scanf("%d", &eno);

            search(linkList, eno);
            break;

        case '5':
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != '5');
}                               /* End of main() */
```

However , when I run the program , the program is not accepting the value for Employee name and directly jumping to Employee designation .

[As you can see in the screenshot of the output linked, it is directly jumping to the employee designation without taking input for employee name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXEo3.png)

Why is this happening ?

**Edit 1: I was told to try replacing 'gets' with 'fgets' . Despite doing that , the computer is still now taking the input for employee name and directly jumping to employee designation**

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 30

struct EMP
{
int empno;
char empName[MAX];
char designation[MAX];
struct EMP *next;
};

/*********************************************************************/
/* Function to insert a node at the front of the linked list. */
/* front: front pointer, id: employee ID, name: employee name */
/* desg: Employee designation */
/* Returns the new front pointer. */
/*********************************************************************/

struct EMP* insert(struct EMP *front, int id, char name[], char desg[])
{
struct EMP *newnode;

newnode = (struct EMP*) malloc(sizeof(struct EMP));

if (newnode == NULL)
{
printf("\nAllocation failed\n");
exit(2);
}
newnode->empno = id;
strcpy(newnode->empName, name);
strcpy(newnode->designation, desg);
newnode->next = front;
front = newnode;
return(front);
} /*End of insert() */

/* Function to display a node in a linked list */
void printNode(struct EMP *p)
{
printf("\nEmployee Details...\n");
printf("\nEmp No : %d", p->empno);
printf("\nName : %s", p->empName);
printf("\nDesignation : %s\n", p->designation);
printf("-------------------------------------\n");
} /*End of printNode() */

/* ********************************************************/
/* Function to deleteNode a node based on employee number */
/* front: front pointer, id: Key value */
/* Returns: the modified list. */
/* ********************************************************/

struct EMP* deleteNode(struct EMP *front, int id)
{
struct EMP *ptr;
struct EMP *bptr; /* bptr is pointing to the node behind ptr */

if (front->empno == id)
{
ptr = front;
printf("\nNode deleted:");
printNode(front);
front = front->next;
free(ptr);
return(front);
}

for(ptr=front->next, bptr=front; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->next, bptr=bptr->next)
{
if (ptr->empno == id)
{
printf("\nNode deleted:");
printNode(ptr);
bptr->next = ptr->next;
free(ptr);
return(front);
}
}
printf("\nEmployee Number %d not found ", id);
return(front);
} /*End of deleteNode() */

/*****************************************************************/
/* Function to search the nodes in a linear fashion based emp ID */
/* front: front pointer, key: key ID. */
/*****************************************************************/
void search(struct EMP *front, int key)
{
struct EMP *ptr;

for (ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr -> next)
{
if (ptr->empno == key)
{
printf("\nKey found:");
printNode(ptr);
return;
}
}
printf("\nEmployee Number %d not found ", key);
} /*End of search() */

/* Function to display the linked list */
void display(struct EMP *front)
{
struct EMP *ptr;

for (ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
{
printNode(ptr);
}
} /*End of display() */

/* Function to display the menu of operations on a linked list */
void menu()
{
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Press 1 to INSERT a node into the list \n");
printf("Press 2 to DELETE a node from the list \n");
printf("Press 3 to DISPLAY the list \n");
printf("Press 4 to SEARCH the list \n");
printf("Press 5 to EXIT \n");
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
} /*End of menu() */

/* Function to select the option */
char option()
{
char choice;

printf("\n\n>> Enter your choice: ");
switch(choice=getche())
{
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
case '4':
case '5': return(choice);
default : printf("\nInvalid choice.");
}
return choice;
} /*End of option() */

/* The main() program begins */
void main()
{
struct EMP *linkList;
char name[21], desig[51];
char choice;
int eno;

linkList = NULL;

printf("\nWelcome to demonstration of singly linked list\n");

menu(); /*Function call */

do {
choice = option(); /*to choose oeration to be performed */

switch(choice)
{
case '1':

printf("\nEnter the Employee Number : ");
scanf("%d", &eno);

printf("Enter the Employee name : ");
    //fflush(stdin);
    fgets(name,MAX,stdin);


printf("Enter the Employee Designation : ");
fgets(desig,MAX,stdin);

linkList = insert(linkList, eno, name, desig);
break;

case '2': printf("\n\nEnter the employee number to be deleted: ");
scanf("%d", &eno);

linkList = deleteNode(linkList, eno);
break;

case '3': if (linkList == NULL)
{
printf("\nList empty.");
break;
}
display(linkList);
break;

case '4': printf("\n\nEnter the employee number to be searched: ");
scanf("%d", &eno);

search(linkList, eno);
break;

case '5': break;
}
} while (choice != '5');
} /*End fo main()*/
```

Comment: [why-gets-is-dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour don't do that. Don't use `gets` it's unsage.  I've seen similar issue somewhere... Also don't post text as images, is it really easier to post an image then just text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input in C. Scanf before gets. Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366509/input-in-c-scanf-before-gets-problem)

Comment: @agent47 Yes since it allows you to specify how many characters to be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer to the question in the title

Input is not taken because you're mixing the **scanf** and **gets** family of functions. `scanf` leaves the new line character in the buffer, and then when you call `fgets` to acquire the new line, but `fgets` finds a new line as the first character and returns immediately.

## Suggestion

Pick only one of the `*get*` and `*scanf*` families to handle your input. You can still use `fgets` to get the input, and then pass it to `sscanf`, to handle the format and retrieve your values.

#### Example

```
do {
    choice = option();      /* to choose oeration to be performed */

    char line_buffer[128];  // Declare your own line buffer
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);  // Set stdin to unbuffered

    switch (choice) {
    case '1':
        printf("\nEnter the Employee Number : ");
        // put input into line buffer
        fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), stdin); 
        // use sscanf on your line_buffer instead of stdin
        sscanf(line_buffer, "%d", &eno); 

        printf("Enter the Employee name : ");
        fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

        printf("Enter the Employee Designation : ");
        fgets(desig, sizeof(desig), stdin);

        linkList = insert(linkList, eno, name, desig);
        break;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `\n` is in buffer `stdin` when you are taking input using `gets()`. `gets()` reads `stdin`(if no buffer is specified) buffer till `\n`.

One naive solution would be read an extra character that that will eat up `\n`.
The idea is you can use any of the following just after using `scanf()` to consume `\n` from the buffer,

1. `gets();`
2. `getc(stdin);`
3. `getchar();`